# How insert Excel file into a varbinary field using SSMS or dbForge Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, dbforge

I have a table in SQL Server with a field that's defined as varbinary. It's going to hold an actual excel (xls) file. Using the SSMS interface (or dbForge Studio interface) how can I insert an actual excel file into an existing record in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [OPENROWSET Bulk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO table_name(varbinary_col_name)
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'path', SINGLE_BLOB) AS binary_data
```

Updating:

```
WITH cte(data_blob) AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'path', SINGLE_BLOB) AS binary_data
)
UPDATE table_name
SET varbinary_col_name = cte.data_blob
FROM cte
WHERE table_name.id = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get it to work for Azure db? I get "Keyword or statement option 'single_blob' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."

Comment: I have no idea. Check manual, your question doesn't mention you use Azure.